# View is not displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4

I have an alert box that takes user input and starts a download task. After the user clicks "Ok," I want the screen to show a UIView that I added an ActivityIndicator to while the download occurs. The download occurs successfully and the function correctly opens up the next controller, however, the custom view nor activity indicator are ever displayed. Here's my code:

```
private func getKeyFromAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Key", message: "Enter your text key below.  If you want to scan it instead, click \"Scan Key.\" ", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        let attribString = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter your app code here")
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = attribString
    }

    let scanAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Scan Key", style: .default) { _ in
        self.openSettingsForApp()
    }
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0]
        if let text = textField.text {
            let encoded = text.toBase64()
            let status = APIKeychain.storeToken(encoded)
            if !status {
                self.displayAlertForBadKeychain(useCamera: false)
            } else {
                self.addLoader()
                self.dismissSetup()
            }
        } else {
            let _ = APIKeychain.storeToken("")
            self.addLoader()
            self.dismissSetup()
        }
    }

    alert.addAction(scanAction)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    show(alert, sender: nil)
}
```

The function in question that I use to display the UIView is `addLoader()`
The code for `addLoader` is:

```
private func addLoader() {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
    let loaderView = UIView(frame: frame)
    loaderView.alpha = 1.0
    loaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let activitySpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: loaderView.frame)
    activitySpinner.center = loaderView.center
    activitySpinner.hidesWhenStopped = false
    activitySpinner.style = .whiteLarge
    activitySpinner.startAnimating()
    loaderView.addSubview(activitySpinner)
    self.view.addSubview(loaderView)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I've tried several iterations of `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsLayout` without luck.  I've also tried explicitly declaring this in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` without any affect as well.

**EDIT**
I added the code below for `dismissSetup()`

```
private func dismissSetup() {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        if self.updateDatabase {
            //This will start the download process
            let _ = WebDataFetcher(dataStack: self.dataStack)
        }
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.wait()
    let mainSB = UIStoryboard(name: "UserInputs", bundle: nil)
    let mainVC = mainSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userInputs")
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainVC
}
```

Comment: What does this `dismissSetup()` does? I've tested it locally and it all ran perfectly.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella, I added the additional code.  I confirmed as well if I commented out the `dismissSetup()` that I got the view I wanted.  That being said, I don't understand why the `dismissSetup()` call would impact that operation.

Comment: Because in dismissSetup() you change the root view controller and so the view created in addLoader() gets overwritten?

Comment: @onnoweb, unfortunately no.  I commented out the three statements after the `dispatchGroup.wait()` and got an interesting result.  The view changed only after the download action completed.